# In Android Studio, how to disable reforamtting code adding a new line after each branch in when statement?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I noticed this when upgrading to Flamingo.

Before it did not add a new line after each branch in `when` statement.

I check the coding convention here: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#control-flow-statements

> In a when statement, if a branch is more than a single line, consider separating it from adjacent case blocks with a blank line:

```
private fun parsePropertyValue(propName: String, token: Token) {
    when (token) {
        is Token.ValueToken ->
            callback.visitValue(propName, token.value)

        Token.LBRACE -> { // ...
        }
    }
}
```

I think this new coding convention. I don't like it because it makes the code longer.

I check settings in Android Studio but I cannot find the setting for it.

Does anyone know how to disable it?

Answer (score 0):

I must be blind. Just found it..
[image]